# Ubuntu 16.04 Unable to upgrade completely

Tags: python, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

Unable to do apt-get upgrade -y on Ubuntu 16.04 successfully,
Tried using both **apt-get upgrade -y** and **apt-get upgrade -y --fix-missing**,
Facing issue in upgrading python3, 
Getting the following warning/error-

```
/home/user# apt-get upgrade -y
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  linux-generic-hwe-16.04 linux-headers-generic-hwe-16.04 linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04 linux-signed-generic-hwe-16.04
  linux-signed-image-generic-hwe-16.04
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up python3-pytango (8.1.8-1) ...
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyTango/tango_gevent.py", line 56
    raise result.error_string, None, result.tb
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

dpkg: error processing package python3-pytango (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3-pytango
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

On observations the issue is faced for python only.,
Tried doing sudo apt-get --reinstall install python3 -

```
Setting up python3-pytango (8.1.8-1) ...
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyTango/tango_gevent.py", line 56
    raise result.error_string, None, result.tb
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

dpkg: error processing package python3-pytango (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3-pytango
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: This is because of your system python version.
you should install python 3 but its better to use virtualenvs.

Comment: Did you try 'sudo apt-get --reinstall install python3' before doing 'sudo apt-get upgrade -y' ? May be you should ask question on [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/)

Comment: @Venkatesh same error, updated logs in question